# Want to know the No. of rows,space used,space reserved in each table against all the databases on server level

Tags: sql-server

I need to find the No. of rows,size of table,index size,data used,datareserved in each table against all the user created database on server level.Is it possible in a single script or query.or i have to query each database.Write now the script which i have got is this.

```
//---script i have to run on each database.
use MyDbName;

GO
CREATE TABLE #TableSpaceUsed
(
       Table_name NVARCHAR(255),
       Table_rows INT,
       Reserved_KB VARCHAR(20),
       Data_KB VARCHAR(20),
       Index_Size_KB VARCHAR(20),
       Unused_KB VARCHAR(20)

)


INSERT INTO #TableSpaceUsed
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'sp_spaceused ''?'''

SELECT TOP 1 db_Name() As DB_Name,Table_name,Table_Rows,
  CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(Index_Size_KB,1,LEN(Index_Size_KB) -2)) as indexSizeKB, 
  CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(Data_KB,1,LEN(Data_KB) -2)) as DBSizeUsed_KB, 
  CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(Reserved_KB,1,LEN(Reserved_KB) -2)) as DBSizeReserved_KB, 
  CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(Unused_KB,1,LEN(Unused_KB) -2)) as unusedKB
  FROM #TableSpaceUsed
  ORDER BY DBSizeUsed_KB DESC

DROP TABLE #TableSpaceUsed
```

Comment: Rather than reinvent the wheel, give sp_BlitzIndex a shot: firstresponderkit.org

Answer (score 1):

I believe one I use provides everything you need?

```
--Table space
SELECT 
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    p.rows AS RowCounts,
    SUM(a.total_pages)/128 AS TotalSpaceMB, 
    SUM(a.used_pages)/128 AS UsedSpaceMB, 
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages))/128 AS UnusedSpaceMB
FROM 
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255
    AND p.[rows] > 500000
GROUP BY 
    t.Name, p.Rows
ORDER BY 
    t.Name
```

Note the conditions in the WHERE statement which may be different for you. This is one I obtained from another website I believe, so it isn't my work! I can't find the reference to which website though...

### EDIT

OK, this one is better, includes non clustered index space, identifies the schema for the tables and includes decimal points:

```
WITH idxs AS (
    SELECT
        t.object_id as TableID,
        t.name AS TableName,
        SUM(a.used_pages)/128.0 AS 'Indexsize(MB)'
        --, i.*
    FROM 
        sys.tables t
        INNER JOIN sys.indexes AS i ON t.object_id = i.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.partitions AS p ON p.OBJECT_ID = i.OBJECT_ID AND p.index_id = i.index_id
        INNER JOIN sys.allocation_units AS a ON a.container_id = p.partition_id
    WHERE i.[type]=2
    GROUP BY t.object_id, t.name
)
SELECT
    s.name AS SchemaName,
    t.NAME AS TableName,
    p.rows AS RowCounts,
    SUM(a.total_pages)/128.0 AS TotalSpaceMB,
    SUM(a.used_pages)/128.0 AS UsedSpaceMB, 
    (SUM(a.total_pages) - SUM(a.used_pages))/128.0 AS UnusedSpaceMB,
    idxs.[Indexsize(MB)]
FROM
    sys.tables t
INNER JOIN      
    sys.indexes i ON t.OBJECT_ID = i.object_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.partitions p ON i.object_id = p.OBJECT_ID AND i.index_id = p.index_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.allocation_units a ON p.partition_id = a.container_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    idxs ON t.object_id = idxs.TableID
WHERE 
    t.NAME NOT LIKE 'dt%' 
    AND t.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND i.OBJECT_ID > 255
    --AND p.[rows] > 500000
GROUP BY 
    s.name, t.Name, p.Rows, idxs.[Indexsize(MB)]
ORDER BY 
    t.Name
```

Comment: Does that query clearly separate data usage versus index usage? It looks like he asked for that in his question.

Comment: Oh yeah, maybe not, will see if I can include indexes...

Comment: Oh, this only does the current database. If you put the above into a stored proc and use a master.sys.sp_MSforeachdb... it should work.

Comment: Be aware sp_MSforeachdb has "issues"... see [this](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/752629/disable-sp-msforeachdb-by-default-or-fix-it) and [this](https://sqlblog.org/2020/08/04/reliable-flexible-replacement-sp_msforeachdb)

Comment: Oh yeah, nice one Max, I had no idea. I better go check a maintenance plan I know...

Comment: Sorry for the late reply....joe you are right i have asked for Data usage vs index usage in separate column and the query which runs on server level should match the result with my query which i run on database level which i have already pasted above.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply....@JoeObbish you are right i have asked for Data usage vs index usage in separate column and the query which runs on server level should match the result with my query which i run on database level which i have already pasted above.

Comment: Hi ashish, notice the 2nd query (after EDIT) should have what you need (though in MB, not in KB). Also includes index space used per table.